# Back button is not disabling for particular screen in android React native

Tags: android, react-native, back-button

I am trying to disable android back button on home screen only.
My code:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
        BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', handleBackBtnPressed);
        return () => {
          BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', handleBackBtnPressed);
      }
    }, [])

    const handleBackBtnPressed = () => {
       navigation.goBack(null);
       return true
    }

const navigateToNextScreen = () => {
                navigation.push('Prmotions');
         }
```

If I remove   `navigation.goBack(null`); back button is disabled for all screen and with above code back button is not disabled at all.
`navigation.navigate("ScreenName")` isn't working for mu scenario to move to next screen that's why I have used navigation.push

Answer (score 0):

I handled it by putting this on all screens where I wanted to go back on back button press.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
        BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', handleBackBtnPressed);
        return () => {
          BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', handleBackBtnPressed);
      }
    }, [])

    const handleBackBtnPressed = () => {
       
       navigation.goBack(null);
       return true
           
    }
```

and put this where I wanted not to go back.

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
        BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', handleBackBtnPressed);
        return () => {
          BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', handleBackBtnPressed);
      }
    }, [])

    const handleBackBtnPressed = () => {

       return true
           
    }
```

I know this might not be best solution but it worked for me pretty well.